# Altium 18 PCB Filter Select X *except* if Y

Tags: altium

I'm trying to create a PCB filter that will allow me to select everything on the board except for components that have an 0402 or 0603 package size. We have a parameter in our passive parts called "Package" which can be '0402' or '0603', so this would be a perfect way to isolate these components.

I can easily select these using this filter query:

```
HasParameterValue('Package','0402') And HasParameterValue('Package','0603')
```

However, if I try to invert this, it selects everything on the board, including the 0402 and 0603 components. I assume this is because the Not operator does not invert the results returned by `HasParameterValue()`...

Since we have a lot of footprints that are 0603 and 0402, and since these could change in the future, I don't want to specify a long list of `Footprint = 'blah0402blah'`. So I tried:

```
Not (Footprint LIKE '*0402*')
```

The Not has the same effect here. I attempted to do "`Not LIKE`" but that is not syntactically valid.

Does anyone know of a way to *remove* or *except* results of the query based on Parameter values or a similar method?

Edit: @LoganF
I have tried it with various paranthetical combinations. Just tried it like this to no avail:

```
(Not HasParameterValue('Package','0402')) And (Not HasParameterValue('Package','0603'))
```

Comment: I would have thought the not keyword would work in this case. Are you sure you didn't make a logical mistake? Not ( 0402 and 0603 ) would return everything, (not 0402) and (not 0603) would get you the right results i think. Edit: actually it depends on the order it evaluates stuff.  If your query from the question works then its different to what i assumed.  I'll check shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will look for an answer using filter queries when I am in front of Altium 18. currently I have Altium 15 available, which doesn't have the function HasParameterValue(), but does have HasParameter(). I have found that you can use

`IsPart and not (HasParameter('Value','10k') or HasParameter('Value','1k'))`

to achieve a similar result, but I don't know if this will hold in Altium 18, since the Altium 15 equivalent of your example filter:

```
HasParameterValue('Value','10k') and HasParameterValue('Value','0R')
```

appears to be or instead of and:

```
HasParameter('Value','10k') or HasParameter('Value','0R')
```

However, in any recent version of Altium you can use "find similar objects" which is very powerful.

the quickest method since you already have a query which selects your unwanted parts:

1. run the query to select your 0603 and 0402 parts
2. right click on any selected part and choose "find similar objects"
3. change the "selected" attribute from "any" to "different" (last row in "graphical")
4. set the scope: in Altium 18, you get "current project/current document/open documents" before 18, you only get "current document/open documents"
5. make sure "clear existing" and "select matching" are both ticked.

when you run this it will invert the selection. you may want to narrow down the objects by setting component type from "any" to "same", object type=part should be set to "same" by default.

I will update this on Monday if I find a query based solution

Answer (score 1):

My guess is when you tried inverting the logic you forgot to switch from AND to OR. In other words your query to select the components is

`HasParameterValue('Package','0402') AND HasParameterValue('Package','0603')`

When you invert the logic you need to have

`NOT (HasParameterValue('Package','0402') **OR** HasParameterValue('Package','0603'))`

Comment: Just realized Logan's answer included this as well. Guess I didn't read carefully enough